# Is there a way to disable custom rules bundles in SonarQube?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, sonarqube

The project does not have any .js or .css files. And even if it did, I added the "sonar.exclusions=**/*.js" line to my sonar-project.properties file. The project can build and run tests with no problem, but when sonarqube is added it throws this error.

```
INFO: Sensor CSS Metrics [javascript]
INFO: Sensor CSS Metrics [javascript] (done) | time=65ms
INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [javascript]
INFO: Deploying custom rules bundle jar:file:/jenkins/.sonar/cache/407d827e66c5794ecc2c8947635359f7/sonar-securityjsfrontend-plugin.jar!/js-vulnerabilities-rules-1.0.0.tgz to /jenkins/workspace/<branch name>/.scannerwork/.sonartmp/eslint-bridge-bundle/package/custom-rules5067734496114002493
ERROR: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandException: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.getVersion(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:190)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.checkNodeCompatibility(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:168)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.build(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:142)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.initNodeCommand(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:183)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.startServer(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:128)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.startServerLazily(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:212)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.AbstractEslintSensor.execute(AbstractEslintSensor.java:66)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.CssRuleSensor.execute(CssRuleSensor.java:96)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:64)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringModuleScanContainer.java:81)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scan(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:392)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:388)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:357)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.SpringGlobalContainer.doAfterStart(SpringGlobalContainer.java:134)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.ProcessWrapperImpl.startProcess(ProcessWrapperImpl.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:75)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 42 common frames omitted

INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [javascript] (done) | time=842ms
INFO: Sensor ThymeLeaf template sensor [securityjavafrontend]
INFO: Sensor ThymeLeaf template sensor [securityjavafrontend] (done) | time=1ms
```

I've tried looking at "https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/" but so far none of the recommended fixes have changed the outcome.

Additionally, there is another error later in the SonarQube INFO output "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The "build-wrapper-dump.json" file was found empty. Please make sure that:" but I don't know if this has anything to do with the above error.

Ultimately, I just want to know how to stop this deployment of custom rules bundle, so I can complete the analysis on the project's C++ code.

Comment: You don't mention SQ version but since 8.9x, they decided to bundle all the plugins and scan for all installed languages. I think the only thing you can do is look for all extensions in your code (it's more than just `.js`;  "JavaScript, TypeScript or CSS code") `find * type f | awk -F'.' '{print  $NF}'| sort -u` and compare to the configuration in `${SQ_URL}/admin/settings?category=JavaScript+%2F+TypeScript` and then you remove the matches. [\[Hint\]](https://github.com/mulesoft-catalyst/mule-sonarqube-plugin/issues/19#issuecomment-754079360)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ian W's comment helped lead to a solution. When the sonar.exclusions included simply **/*.js, the error was occurring, but when I look for more than just .js ("JavaScript, TypeScript or CSS code" as per Ian W's comment) the error changed into simply a warning

"JavaScript/TypeScript/CSS rules were not executed. Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?"

which allowed the rest of the analysis to be executed completely.

As for specifically why this was happening, the code does have some CSS files but those are for formatting, and we don't require node for this project at all. So this solution helped solve this particular problem.